# Is there a way to detect if a function is overridden?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual-functions

Suppose we have an abstract Base class that is inherited:

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        Base() {}
        virtual ~Base() {}
        virtual void on_event_foo(int) {}
        virtual void on_event_bar(int) {}
};

struct Concrete : public Base
{
        virtual void on_event_foo(int value) {/*do some stuff with @value*/}
};
```

Is it a way to know (at compile time would be the best) the `virtual` functions from `Base` that was overridden (with some code in constructor, or with a special pattern)?

My purpose is to implement a wrapper for a library that use some callbacks ; and if I can do check the overriden functions, I will create only the callbacks the user wants.

I want the user can choose the function he wants to override. Then in my code, I will create callbacks only for the overridden functions. The pure `virtual` functions are not a solution, because they cannot permit to create a concrete class without overriding all of them.

In the constructor of `Base`, for now, I connect a **lot** of static callback functions of `Base` within a C API. In those functions, I call the corresponding member function. For example, the callback function is `static Base::EventFoo(/* ... */)` that calls inside `object->on_event_foo(/* .. */)`. This is because I cannot give a member function as a callback to a C library.
But creating too much callbacks make my wrapper slower. So, I want to connect only the callback that the user wants, ie knowing the functions there are overriden by him.

Comment: Make the functions in the base class pure virtual: `virtual void on_event_foo(int) = 0;`.

Comment: you *may* be able to do something with comparing member-to-function pointers

Comment: @vu1p3n0x like comparing `Base::on_event_bar` and `Concrete::on_event_bar`, you mean?

Comment: @Boiethios Sounds like a design flaw for me. You should make your code like that its completely transparent, if a derived class was overriding the function or not.

Comment: I have replaced "overload" with "override" everywhere. It will be good, if you can given an example of what exactly you want. Your last few statements are unclear.

Comment: @Boiethios after some research, it can't be done how I originally envisioned. But it can be done if you change some things

Comment: It isn't usually known at compile time, ergo you can't detect it at compile time. It may not be known until link time at best. XY problem.

Comment: @EJP I removed *at compile time*: the solution of Bathsheba seems to be good.

Comment: Formally, that is not an **abstract** class. In C++ an abstract class has at least one pure virtual function.

Comment: @PeteBecker in my real code, `Base` is an abstract class. I "emulate" that in my example by doing the constructor protected, for the minimalism of my code.

Comment: 'At compile time' still appears in your question. It is therefore unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: @EJP I have edited the passage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I've been notified that this behavior is unspecified since it relies on comparing virtual member function pointers:

> [expr.eq] ... if either is a pointer to a virtual member function, the result is unspecified.

Wording is present in all C++ standards (that I could check). Your results may vary.

---

If you are willing to change a few things, you can use the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to determine if the function is overridden

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Derived>
struct Base
{
    virtual void on_event() {}
    
    void raise_event()
    {
        if (&Derived::on_event == &Base::on_event)
            std::cout << "not overridden" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "overridden" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Concrete1 : Base<Concrete1>
{
    virtual void on_event() override {}
};

struct Concrete2 : Base<Concrete2>
{
    // no override
};

int main()
{
    Concrete1 c1;
    Concrete2 c2;
    
    c1.raise_event(); // prints overridden
    c2.raise_event(); // prints not overridden
    
    return 0;
}
```

The statement `&Derived::on_event == &Base::on_event` should be resolved at compile-time (if that's what you're worried about) and the `if` can be optimized away.

Though I agree with others' opinions that this seems like a poor pattern. It would be much simpler to have the base class have empty event handlers like you already have.

Comment: Hmm, I will see that. That seems to be a good idea: in the `Base` constructor, I check if there is overridden, and then I connect the callback.

Comment: could you static_assert based on offsetof? Then you get a compile time failure.

Comment: @Bathsheba possibly, but I don't see how that'd be much better than what I have. I had originally envisioned it without the need for the template but apparently you can't do `&on_event` or `this->on_event` to get the currently pointed to virtual member function

Comment: @Boiethios also, if you want to use this in an abstract manner, you may need to make a base-base class that the templated `Base` class inherits from. (because all the `Base<...>` classes are different)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x yes I know. That is not the problem. I am currently testing this solution, but that takes time.

Comment: There is just a little problem, I must cast it to `void *`, otherwise it does not work. And that cast makes a warning at compilation. This is strange: the test `&Derived::on_event == &Base::on_event` is always true in my case ; while the pointers are different.

Comment: How do you expect this to be used? All the concrete have different base classes now.

Comment: @Barry I create an interface that Base inherits from.

Comment: @DieterLücking not really, he just wanted to know if the function was overridden and this still satisfies it even when adding another base

Comment: how can you check a private member function?

Comment: @Boiethios I had the same issue with casting to `void *` since `&Derived::on_event == &Base::on_event` was always true. For me, I was able to use it without the cast to `void *` by not having `on_event` be virtual in Base.

Comment: The C++ standard says about the equality operator in [expr.eq] that "If either [operand] is a pointer to a virtual member function, the result is unspecified.". So this is not a portable solution (which explains why it does not work for some commenters).

Comment: @NordicMainframe ah thanks, that makes sense... unfortunately. I'm a bit out of the C++ world lately, but I added a disclaimer highlighting this issue.

Answer (score 2):

With modern c++ you can do this:

```cpp
if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<decltype(&Derived::foo), decltype(&Base::foo)>) {
    std::cout << "overrided" << std::endl;
}
```

You may want to define a macro like this:

```cpp
#define OVERRIDED(B, D, name) !std::is_same_v<decltype(&B::name), decltype(&D::name)>
```

Comment: This does not work if `foo` is overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `virtual` methods at all. If all you want is given some concrete type, `Concrete`, to hook it up to a bunch of callbacks based on the presence of member functions then we can use templates.

For a given type and function name, we can determine if `&T::func` exists at compile time. If it does, we add that callback. So we end up with a whole bunch of things like:

```
template <class T>
void setup_cbs(T& object) {
    T* ptr_to_object = ...; // store somewhere

    static_if<has_on_event_foo<T>>(
        [](auto ptr){ 
            add_event_foo_callback(ptr, [](void* p, int i) {
                using U = decltype(ptr);
                static_cast<U>(p)->on_event_foo(i);
            })
        }),
        [](auto ){}
        )(ptr_to_object);
```

I'm assuming the callback adder takes a pointer and a callback. You will separately have to figure out how to store the pointers, but that seems easier.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x There are so many questions on here about how to do that.